# How to know if you have a non-contiguous list in Python?

Tags: python, memory

For arbitrarily large N, it isn't possible to store all the data in a list contiguously in memory.

For instance, in Python, if I do arr = [0] * N, for large enough N, this can't be contiguous.

What does Python do for this? I assume it gets stored non-contiguously. How does that work?

Answer (score 1):

CPython lists are always contiguous, at least in virtual memory. (There's little they could do to reasonably control physical contiguity and little reason to try.) CPython makes no attempt to break lists into noncontiguous segments in the face of memory fragmentation or anything like that.

If you want to see for yourself, take a look at [`Include/listobject.h`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Include/listobject.h) and [`Objects/listobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c). There's nothing in there about noncontiguous lists.